# Use AWS Spot instances for build agents?

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-devops, agent, master-slave

Use AWS Spot instances for build agents?

Our infra setup is in AWS but we use Azure DevOps for repo, boards & pipelines. To run automated tests like cucumber, we need private agent. if there's a way to utilize spot instances for builds instead of having to have agents always on?

or

can we have a Master slave setup, like how Jenkins has?

Comment: Hi Ajith,
Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the self-hosted agent configuration, we can set the agent to run as service, If you configured the agent to run as a service, it starts automatically. You can view and control the agent running status from the services snap-in.

If we configured the agent to run interactively, open org settings->Agent pools->select agent pool and click the tab Agents, we can see the agent status is Offline if we do not open the run.cmd, if we need to use the agent, we can open the agent file run.cmd to run the agent.

Please refer this link for more details: [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#run-the-agent)

[image]